# Can moderators use your account to downvote answers that you've voted up?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, moderators

I have been asking lots of questions about Python and PyQt lately. There's been a user who was constantly helping me figure out my problems. Every time he answers, it's always the right answer and I always accept and upvote his answer.

This morning I went to Stack Overflow and found out all of the upvotes I gave him were downvoted using my account. Is that a thing or has my Stack Overflow account been hacked?

Comment: Are you talking about serial vote reversal? This just cancels out the up-votes and associated rep.. It doesn't actively convert them to downvotes.

Comment: Your votes were invalidated. No one "downvoted" the user, the votes were just cancelled, as if they had never been cast. If most/all of your votes were for this user, you probably looked to be targeting the user with votes, and that kind of thing gets invalidated.

Comment: Also, I just looked, and they score says one, but if I click to show the ratio it says +0 -0...

Comment: Not sure if that's what it is exactly but all of the upvotes I gave the user who helped me have been reversed.

Comment: @Mithrandir IIRC, there's a separate script that runs that will update the scores for each post. I believe it runs every night, so they'll likely be correct tomorrow.

Comment: I presume this is the account. http://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc?tab=reputation. That is the reversal script.

Comment: Yes that's it. Does that mean I gave him too many upvotes?

Comment: Yes. It crossed the threshold for suspiciousness if they were automatically undone.

Comment: Likely, it means just that. If it looked suspicious, as in most or all of your votes were for them, then that's why the votes were invalidated. As a note, don't go and re-upvote everything. If you do that, it'd just get reversed the next time the script runs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: I recommend someone post this as an answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Moderators can't vote for you. They can reverse votes if deemed suspicious.

There is a serial voting detection script that runs every night at 3 o'clock. That script automatically detected a suspected fraudulent use of votes.

Most likely, the number of votes you gave to a single user over a longer period eventually triggered the script to reverse all of those votes. The specifics of the script isn't given, but this is most likely what happened.

It could also have been the case that a moderator manually reverted your votes but I guess you would have received a moderator message about that by now.

Don't go back and upvote all those posts again. It will trigger the same script but faster than before. It will not work out for you and the user you've voted on.

You can do two things. Leave it like this, move on and be more careful of your votes, or flag one of your posts for a moderator to review the case. Just explain what happened. I guess the moderator has to contact the team about what happened, so it could take some time before you have any feedback on this.

For the future, try not to upvote this user alone, but also other useful contributions within your preferred tag. That might help lift some suspicions.

Comment: Hi @Patrick. I have been harmed by the downvotes. I always answer questions related to python and pyqt because they are tools that I use routinely. And I have removed 200 points, I am only a month in this group and I am discouraged to have this result.

Comment: I understand that. I have had removed even more points because someone thought it was a good idea to mass-upvote me. You can also raise a flag, but I would just be a little patient.

Comment: @eyllanesc what downvotes? Upvotes being retracted is not the same as a downvote.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I really like eyllanesc's answers which is why I upvoted them. Me being a Python and PyQt beginner, I learned a lot from his answers.

Comment: Technically, moderators can't reverse votes. We can only point out to a handful of SE employees that votes should be invalidated, with our evidence that people were coordinating votes. They then have to look into the votes and our evidence themselves and invalidate the votes only if they agree with our assessment, which isn't always the case.

Comment: If your asking more than 3 questions a day and voting the same user's answer to each of those questions, that's very suspicious so stop doing that.  The user still got the reputation for you accepting the their answer to your question.  Move on a couple dozen reputations is nothing